# How do you create a SwiftUI view that takes an optional secondary View argument?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a custom SwiftUI view that acts like the default views where I can add extra content to a view with a method or optional initializer argument.

```swift
SomeCustomView(title: "string argument") {
    // some view
}

SomeCustomView(title: "hello") {
    // some view
}.sideContent {
    // another view
}

// This style is acceptable too
SomeCustomView(title: "hello", sideContent: { /* another view */ }) {
    // some view
}
```

How can I modify this view struct to behave like the above example?

```swift
struct SomeCustomView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let title: String
    let content: Content

    init(title: String, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.title = title
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
            content
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd have two different body "templates" that I could switch between depending on if the `sideContent` method was called or `sideContent` parameter was set. For example,

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(title)
        content
    }
}

// or

var otherBody: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
            content
        }
        sideContent
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have a Group so you can just say `if` and include a side view or not according to some property?

Comment: @matt I tried something like that, but I couldn't figure out how to accept an arbitrary optional view that could be `nil` or maybe `EmptyView`.

Comment: I see what you mean.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*November 2021 update (Works in Xcode 11.x, 12.x, and 13.x)*

After some thought and a bit of trial and error, I figured it out. It seems a bit obvious in hindsight.

```swift
struct SomeCustomView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let title: String
    let content: Content

    init(title: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.title = title
        self.content = content()
    }

    // returns a new View that includes the View defined in 'body'
    func sideContent<SideContent: View>(@ViewBuilder side: @escaping () -> SideContent) -> some View {
        HStack {
            self     // self is SomeCustomView
            side() 
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
            content
        }
    }
}
```

It works with or without the method call.

```swift
SomeCustomView(title: "string argument") {
    // some view
}

SomeCustomView(title: "hello") {
    // some view
}.sideContent {
    // another view
}
```

Previous code with subtle bug: `body` should be `self`

```swift
    func sideContent<SideContent: View>(@ViewBuilder side: @escaping () -> SideContent) -> some View {
        HStack {
            body // <--- subtle bug, updates to the main View are not propagated 
            side() 
        }
    }
```

Thank you Jordan Smith for pointing this out a long time ago.

Comment: Excellent solution. Works like a charm and very in the SwiftUI paradigm.

Comment: this doesnt work with xcode 11 and swift ui 1.0

if you try to call it without sideContent closure parameter it will say "Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred"

Comment: @AntonShevtsov Try adding `<SideContent: View>` to the function? Works for me in Xcode 11.6

Comment: There's a subtle but important bug here: by using 'body', we're running the body view builder at the current point in time, and omitting the view that created the body. For a static view like the one shown here, this is fine - but for anything more dynamic (e.g. perhaps you have some @State variables or preference keys), the returned view will no longer function as expected, since it no longer encapsulates any state associated with the view. Instead of using body, I'd suggest using the view itself, which carries forward any state etc.

Answer (score 23):

A pattern I've followed for container views is to use conditional extension conformance to support initializers for the different variations.

Here's an example of a simple Panel view with an optional Footer.

```swift
struct Panel<Content: View, Footer: View>: View {
    
    let content: Content
    let footer: Footer?
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content, footer: (() -> Footer)? = nil) {
        self.content = content()
        self.footer = footer?()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            content

            // Conditionally check if footer has a value, if desirable.
            footer
        }
    }
}

// Support optional footer
extension Panel where Footer == EmptyView {
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.footer = nil
    }
}
```

---

I believe this is similar to what Apple does to support all the variations of the built-in types. For example, here's a snippet of the headers for a `Button`.

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension Button where Label == PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration.Label {

    /// Creates an instance representing the configuration of a
    /// `PrimitiveButtonStyle`.
    @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
    public init(_ configuration: PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration)
}

@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension Button where Label == Text {

    /// Creates an instance with a `Text` label generated from a localized title
    /// string.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - titleKey: The key for the localized title of `self`, describing
    ///       its purpose.
    ///     - action: The action to perform when `self` is triggered.
    public init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, action: @escaping () -> Void)

    /// Creates an instance with a `Text` label generated from a title string.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - title: The title of `self`, describing its purpose.
    ///     - action: The action to perform when `self` is triggered.
    public init<S>(_ title: S, action: @escaping () -> Void) where S : StringProtocol
}
```

Comment: This is a great way to pass down children content and take additional content as modifiers, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a `ViewModifyer` instead of custom Views. Those work like the follwing:

```swift
struct SideContent<SideContent: View>: ViewModifier {

    var title: String
    var sideContent: (() -> SideContent)?

    init(title: String) {
         self.title = title
    }

    init(title: String, @ViewBuilder sideContent: @escaping () -> SideContent) {
         self.title = title
         self.sideContent = sideContent
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
          VStack {
             Text(title)
             content
           }
           sideContent?()
        }
    }
}
```

This may be used as `SomeView().modifier(SideContent(title: "asdasd") { Text("asdasd")})`, however, if you omit the side, you still need to specify its type `SomeView().modifier(SideContent<EmptyView>(title: "asdasd"))`

#### UPDATE

Removing the title it simplifies, as you mentioned.

```swift
struct SideContent<SideContent: View>: ViewModifier {

    var sideContent: (() -> SideContent)

    init(@ViewBuilder sideContent: @escaping () -> SideContent) {
        self.sideContent = sideContent
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
            content
            sideContent()
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can make a modifier for `Title`.

```swift
struct Titled: ViewModifier {

    var title: String

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
            content
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
SomeView()
   .modifier(Titled(title: "Title"))
   .modifier(SideContent { Text("Side") })
```

Comment: If you want to use "templates", either use `Group` or cast to `AnyView` at the end of the expression, so the types would match.

Comment: This technique works, but it's a little ugly. You can leave the `title` param in `SomeView` and avoid `SideContent<EmptyView>`